# Adding embedded build status icon to github

Tags: github, jenkins

I'm trying to add status icon from Jenkins to GitHub README.md file but the icon doesn't display.

The `Embeddable Build Status Icon` plugin is installed on Jenkins.

I searched for solutions and found out that I need to change the "configure security" on Jenkins (I activated the Job->ViewStatus checkbox at the "Matrix-based security" for the Anonymous user) but it didn't work.

I tried to add someone else status icon to the README file and it works, so I think the problem is from Jenkins.

The row that I'm trying to add to README is:

```
![Build Status](http://3.213.40.221:8080/buildStatus/icon?job=1_Load_Build_Staging)
```

The link [status icon](http://3.213.40.221:8080/buildStatus/icon?job=1_Load_Build_Staging) works, but doesn't display on README

Anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I have exactly the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Github caches README images, according to [Aggressive image caching breaks image badges #24](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/224), so my guess is that either:

1. Your build icon is not visible to Github's caching proxy, or
2. Your jenkins status server is not serving correct HTTP caching headers

Comment: Thanks for respond. Do you know how to set this up?

Comment: I can't access that status icon, so I'm assuming Github can't either. Is that Jenkins server supposed to be public?

Comment: really? I tried to access the status icon in incognito mode and it works. The Jenkins server is private but I edited the security configuration that anonymous user can view the status of a job, so it odd that you couldn't access the link :\

Comment: @Idan.c: if you found any solution for this issue kindly post the solution.